# I cannot connect to my AWS EC2 url and I have a feeling it has something to do with my security group settings

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, connectivity, aws-security-group

I am very new to coding so trying to figure this out was very hard for me. I'm trying to deploy my code with docker and running my code inside the EC2 cloud. But I can't seem to get the instance's url to work. I set my inbound (security group) HTTP (80) => 0.0.0.0/0, HTTPs (443) => 0.0.0.0/0, and SSH(22) => my ip. I read that setting my SSH to 0.0.0.0/0 was a bad idea, so I went with my ip (there was an option called 'my ip'). Also, I am using ubuntu for my AMI.

While successfully docker using (docker-compose up), I used `curl http://localhost:3001` (3001 is my exposed port inside my code) and it works fine. But when I used `curl ec2-XX-XXX-XXX-XXX.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com`, it outputs: 
`curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ssh` and
`curl: (7) Failed to connect to ec2-XX-XXX-XXX-XXX.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com port 80: Connection refused`

Comment: what is xx-xxx part? is that public ip? if not then it could not wotk.

Comment: It was a public ip. I just didn't know if I should show it or not.

Comment: You can freely share the public ip. It is called public for a reason. Without your key pair no one can log onto it.

Comment: Why in the `curl ec2-XX-XXX-XXX-XXX.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com` you don't use 3001 as when using `curl http://localhost:3001`?

Answer (score 1):

Curl ec2-xxx-xx-amazonaws.com send request on port 80 , while you are docker is running at port 3001.

1. First verify that you have exposed some host port to docker. Something like this should come in docker ps -a
   0.0.0.0/3001--> 3001 . the first 3001 can be any host port
2. Next make sure that the first port whichever you used is there in security group and opened for your ip.

Hopefully if all good at vpc and route tables settings then :3001(use whatever host port you gave if used anything apart of 3001) all should work